# I'm having a bit of trouble with the Javascript Onclick event when trying to toggle between images

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, src

So for one of my labs, I'm trying to get a blurred image with one src to appear as a clear image from a different source.  So far I've only managed to change the blurred image to the clear image, but not the other way around.

So far, I have the if statement and a string indexOf as a part of my lab requirements.  Now bear in mind that by my instructions, I'm not allowed to edit any HTML for this project.

```
function toggleImages(){

//(document.getElementById("clickimage").src = 'images/lab9_blurred');
//console.log(str.indexOf("clickimage"));
//var images = 'images/lab9_blurred.jpg';

var str = "images/lab9_blurred.jpg";
   console.log(str.indexOf("blurred"));

var str =   "images/lab9_clear.jpg";
   console.log(str.indexOf("clear")) 

//click it once, it's true, click it again, it's false.  That's what should happen.  But how do we do that?
//If image = "images/lab9_blurred.jpg" then for variable image we get clickimage, set variable name to lab 9 clear, and set image source to name.  

//if (fake == true){
if (str.indexOf("blurred") == 12){

    var image = document.getElementById("clickimage");
    var name = "images/lab9_blurred.jpg";
    image.src = name;       
        console.log(str.indexOf("blurred"));
} 
else if (str.indexOf("clear") == 12)
{

    var image = document.getElementById("clickimage");
    var name = "images/lab9_clear.jpg";
    image.src = name;
        console.log(str.indexOf("clear"));
    }   
};

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: You've to put the src of the image to `str` instead of a hard-coded string. Note, that the returned value of `src` contains the full URL to the image, no matter what was written to the markup or set to `src` property.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try following code...

```
function toggleImages(){

    var image = document.getElementById("clickimage");

    if (image.src.indexOf("blurred") == 12)
    {
        var str =   "images/lab9_clear.jpg";
        console.log(str.indexOf("clear")) 
    } 
    else
    {
        var str = "images/lab9_blurred.jpg";
        console.log(str.indexOf("blurred"));
    }
    image.src = str;
};

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: I tried this, I'm getting the console log but the image isn't toggling.

Comment: @ColtMason hey you can see same code in following link  https://jsfiddle.net/spankajd/rh0y3pf5/